# validating user input to text only and integer only

Tags: input, validating

i have searched for a simple, non complicated answer on how to ensure that the user is asked again if they enter anything other than text for 1 and an integer for 2.

when entering these input variables, however i have only found complicated solutions that my teacher wont acccept.

is it possible if anyone can provide me with simple solutions on how to validate these variables. so far all i know how to validate is to use "while not in" functions, which only works for specific options. I am new to python, so please explain in a simple manner. thanks! :)

```
1-studentname=input("what is your name?:") 
2-print("what is 10+10?:")
3-studentanswer=int(input("insert answer:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop with if , else in it

```
while(true):
   t = int(input());
   if t == 1:
     # do whatever --> break at the end
   else if t == 2:
     # do whatever ---> break at the end
   else:
     continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.isalpha` and `.isdigit method`.
For example,

```
studentname=input("what's your name) ?
studentname.isalpha()
```

That checks whether the string consists of alphabetic characters only.
Both `.isalpha` and `.isdigit` return boolean, so you can use an if condition then.